How to avoid duplicated headers in source-tree using `add_subdirectory` in qt-creator?
Using CMake project in qt-creator, the IDE shows duplicated headers in the source tree.

(Qt-creator version 9.0.2)
When I navigate through the sources, groups of files are expanded and it become quickly inpractical to find a filename in that huge tree.
What I would like is something like this:

Notes:

I know that I can "Show simplified tree": this isn't helpful because it also flatten all the directory hierarchy.
CMAKE groups are not helping.


Minimal? example:
Top CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(TARGET "Test_Cmake")
project("${TARGET}")

add_executable(${TARGET})
add_subdirectory("Model")

set( SOURCES classA.cpp )
set( HEADERS classA.hpp )
#source_group("${TARGET}" FILES "${SOURCES};${HEADERS}")
set( LIBS Model)
target_sources( ${TARGET} PRIVATE ${SOURCES} PUBLIC ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${LIBS} )

Model CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(TARGET "Model")

add_library(${TARGET})
set( SOURCES classB.cpp )
set( HEADERS classB.hpp )
#source_group("${TARGET}" FILES "${SOURCES};${HEADERS}")
target_sources( ${TARGET} PRIVATE ${SOURCES} PUBLIC ${HEADERS})

How to create the files:
mkdir Test_cmake && cd "$_"
touch classA.cpp classA.hpp CMakeLists.txt
mkdir Model && cd "$_"
touch classB.cpp classB.hpp CMakeLists.txt
# Then copy above content in each CMakeLists.txt


You add classB.hpp header to the target Model as PUBLIC. So the header belongs also to the target Test_cmake, which is linked with Model.

Hmm, you are totally right, I didn't understood correctly this PUBLIC stuff.
I wonder if to close the question now..

A recent question about other problems with PUBLIC headers. That question could be treated as duplicate of yours because of the same core problem (using PUBLIC keyword in target_sources) ... But at the same time the questions could be viewed differently because of different symptoms.

Actually, I find your question to be good in showing a problem which could be quite popular. So you may just write an answer.

I would not put "That question" as duplicate of mine, eventually the reverse (that question is more generic than mine).
Either your write shortly your first comment as an answer and I accept it, or I will write an answer myself. Let see if people see that as interesting, or we close it.

You add classB.hpp header to the target Model as PUBLIC:
target_sources( ${TARGET} PRIVATE ${SOURCES} PUBLIC ${HEADERS})

So the header belongs also to the target Test_cmake, which is linked with Model. This is why IDE shows given header in the tree for both targets, Model and Test_cmake.
For avoid that, use PRIVATE keyword. Usually, the command target_sources is used with PRIVATE keyword only, so it adds sources and the headers only for the single target.
(Note, that accessibility of a header in the consumer target via #include is regulated by the target_include_directories command and its keywords.)
